# HABTM associations with another table

Tags: cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many

I'm in trouble with a more complex situation of HABTM in Cakephp. Ina nutshel, the situation is: a have users and movies, the relationship between then is HABTM, but i also need a relationship types.

```
USERS - HABTM - MOVIES

          |

    RELATION_TYPES
```

The relationship between users and movies could be many different types: author type, public type, etc.

When i try to use the contain behavior, i get an error message that says:

> Model "MoviesUser" is not associated with model "RelationType".

But all the models are associated.

These are the models:

**User Model**

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Movie' => array(
        'className' => 'Movie',
        'joinTable' => 'movies_users',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'movie_id',
        'unique' => 'keepExisting',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => 'Movie.title',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'deleteQuery' => '',
        'insertQuery' => ''
    )
);
```

**Movie Model**

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'User' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'joinTable' => 'movies_users',
        'foreignKey' => 'movie_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'user_id',
        'unique' => 'keepExisting',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'deleteQuery' => '',
        'insertQuery' => ''
    )
);
```

**MoviesUser Model**

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'User' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    ),
    'Movie' => array(
        'className' => 'Movie',
        'foreignKey' => 'movie_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    ),
    'RelationType' => array(
        'className' => 'RelationType',
        'foreignKey' => 'relation_type_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);
```

In the MoviesController, i'm trying to get some movies and the relation with users and the type of the relation. Here is where i call the Contain on Movies Controller:

```
$this->Movie->contain(array(
    'Person' => array(
        'order' => array(
            'Person.name'=>'ASC'
        ),
        'Activity'
    ),
    'Country' => array(
        'order'=>array(
            'Country.name'=>'ASC'
        )
    ),
    'User'=>array(
        'conditions'=>array(
            'User.id'=>$this->Session->read('Auth.User.id')
        ),
        'MoviesUser'=>array(
            'RelationType'
        )
    )
));
```

When i try to run this i get the message Model "MoviesUser" is not associated with the model "RelationType".

The fields of movies_user are:
id, user_id, relation_type_id, rate, comment

The fields of relation_types are:
id, title

And here my $has_many property on RelationType Model:

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'MoviesUser' => array(
        'className' => 'MoviesUser',
        'foreignKey' => 'relation_type_id',
        'dependent' => false,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'exclusive' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'counterQuery' => ''
    )
);
```

Comment: paste in the code from your respective models which describes the relationships

Comment: Hi @joshua.paling, here are the models! Thanks in advance!

Comment: could you post the fields of `movies_users` and `relation_types`?

Comment: Paste in the code you're using that makes use of the containable behaviour.

Comment: Hi @joshua.paling, there is the contain call

Comment: In your relationtypes model, have you made sure to define the right $hasMany MoveUsers ?

Comment: Yes @joshua.paling . I added this block of code to my post. Strange, no? Actually i solved the problem using a JOIN, but would be a more clear solution to use the CONTAIN behaviour. Thats why i still looking for a solution on this way.